# Parse XML with Python with title and value on different lines

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have the following XML document that i would like to write to a csv file.

```
<items>
  <item>
    <attribute type="set" identifier="naadloos">
      <name locale="nl_NL">Naadloos</name>
      <value locale="nl_NL" identifier="nee">Nee</value>
    </attribute>
    <attribute type="asset" identifier="short_description">
      <value locale="nl_NL">Tom beugel bh</value>
    </attribute>
    <attribute type="text" identifier="name">
      <name locale="nl_NL">Naam</name>
      <value>Marie Jo L'Aventure Tom beugel bh</value>
    </attribute>
    <attribute type="int" identifier="is_backorder">
      <name locale="nl_NL">Backorder</name>
      <value>2</value>
    </attribute>
  </item>
</items>
```

how can i retrieve the data from this format? I need the following output

```
naadloos, short_description, name, is_Backorder
Nee, Tom beugel bh, Marie Jo L'Adventure Tom beugel bh, 2
```

so i need the identifier from the attribute line, and the text from the value line.

Any ideas?

Much appreciated

Comment: Take a look at [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Comment: that ping on the code writing service timed out; try a larger packet including some code you wrote yet.

Comment: As @RichardJones stated, ElementTree is the tool for the job, but you may want to add some code for us to help you.

Comment: As you only have one file, you could open it in Excel, and save as CSV. Job done :-)

Comment: Have you got your solution!\

Answer (score 0):

This is my try it gets `elements` by `attribute` and writes them into a specified file by `dictwriter`!

```
import lxml.etree as et
import csv

#headers={}
xml= """<items>
  <item>
    <attribute type="set" identifier="naadloos">
      <name locale="nl_NL">Naadloos</name>
      <value locale="nl_NL" identifier="nee">Nee</value>
    </attribute>
    <attribute type="asset" identifier="short_description">
      <value locale="nl_NL">Tom beugel bh</value>
    </attribute>
    <attribute type="text" identifier="name">
      <name locale="nl_NL">Naam</name>
      <value>Marie Jo L'Aventure Tom beugel bh</value>
    </attribute>
    <attribute type="int" identifier="is_backorder">
      <name locale="nl_NL">Backorder</name>
      <value>2</value>
    </attribute>
  </item>
</items>
"""

tree = et.fromstring(xml)
header = []
for i in tree.xpath("//attribute/@identifier"):
    header.append(i)
def dicter(x):
    exp = r"//attribute[@identifier='%s']/value/text()"%x
    tmp = ''.join(tree.xpath(exp))
    d = [x,tmp]
    return d
data = dict(dicter(i) for i in header)
#Now write data into file
with open(r"C:\Users\User_Name\Desktop\output.txt",'wb') as wrt:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(wrt,header)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(data)
```

Written file content-

```
naadloos,short_description,name,is_backorder
Nee,Tom beugel bh,Marie Jo L'Aventure Tom beugel bh,2
```